# How to design totally different templates for different devices, like mobile and desktop, but also tablet in Angular?

Tags: html, angular, bootstrap-4, progressive-web-apps, ngx-bootstrap

So I have a angular 9 application.

And I have some mockups. But the template on mobile looks totally different then on dekstop.

But the data(API calls) are almost identical on both(desktop, mobile). Almost. So it even can differ for mobile and for desktop.

But so my question. Is this the best 'approach'? Or is it better to work with media queries?

So this is for desktop:

```
<!-- <app-bar-chart></app-bar-chart> -->

<div>
  <router-outlet></router-outlet>
</div>
  <div class="w-100 d-lg-block d-md-block">
    <div class="d-none d-lg-block d-md-block">
      <mat-grid-list cols="4" rowHeight="1:2">
        <mat-grid-tile colspan="1">
          <div class="nested-grid-list">
            <mat-grid-list cols="1" rowHeight="3:2">
              <mat-grid-tile *ngFor="let card of cards; let i = index;" [colspan]="card.cols" [rowspan]="card.rows">
                <cdk-drop-list [cdkDropListConnectedTo]="drops" [cdkDropListData]="i">
                  <mat-card cdkDrag (cdkDragEntered)="entered($event)" [cdkDragData]="i" class="dashboard-card"
                    [style.backgroundColor]="card.color">
                    <mat-card-content class="dashboard-card-content">
                      <div class="example-handle" cdkDragHandle>
                        <svg width="24px" fill="currentColor" viewBox="0 0 24 24">
                          <path
                            d="M10 9h4V6h3l-5-5-5 5h3v3zm-1 1H6V7l-5 5 5 5v-3h3v-4zm14 2l-5-5v3h-3v4h3v3l5-5zm-9 3h-4v3H7l5 5 5-5h-3v-3z">
                          </path>
                          <path d="M0 0h24v24H0z" fill="none"></path>
                        </svg>
                      </div>
                    </mat-card-content>jhjhjhj
                  </mat-card>
                </cdk-drop-list>
              </mat-grid-tile>
            </mat-grid-list>
          </div>
        </mat-grid-tile>
        <mat-grid-tile colspan="2">
          <div class="nested-grid-list">
            <mat-grid-list cols="1" rowHeight="3:1">
              <mat-grid-tile *ngFor="let card of cards2; let i = index;" [colspan]="card.cols" [rowspan]="card.rows">
                <cdk-drop-list [cdkDropListConnectedTo]="drops" [cdkDropListData]="i">
                  <mat-card cdkDrag (cdkDragEntered)="entered2($event)" [cdkDragData]="i" class="dashboard-card"
                    [style.backgroundColor]="card.color">
                    <mat-card-content class="dashboard-card-content">
                      <div class="example-handle" cdkDragHandle>
                        <svg width="24px" fill="currentColor" viewBox="0 0 24 24">
                          <path
                            d="M10 9h4V6h3l-5-5-5 5h3v3zm-1 1H6V7l-5 5 5 5v-3h3v-4zm14 2l-5-5v3h-3v4h3v3l5-5zm-9 3h-4v3H7l5 5 5-5h-3v-3z">
                          </path>
                          <path d="M0 0h24v24H0z" fill="none"></path>
                        </svg>
                      </div>
                    </mat-card-content>
                  </mat-card>
                </cdk-drop-list>
              </mat-grid-tile>
            </mat-grid-list>
          </div>
        </mat-grid-tile>
        <mat-grid-tile colspan="1">
          <div class="nested-grid-list">
            <mat-grid-list cols="1" rowHeight="3:2">
              <mat-grid-tile *ngFor="let card of cards3; let i = index;" [colspan]="card.cols" [rowspan]="card.rows">
                <cdk-drop-list [cdkDropListConnectedTo]="drops" [cdkDropListData]="i">
                  <mat-card cdkDrag (cdkDragEntered)="entered3($event)" [cdkDragData]="i" class="dashboard-card"
                    [style.backgroundColor]="card.color">
                    <mat-card-content class="dashboard-card-content">
                      <div class="example-handle" cdkDragHandle>
                        <svg width="24px" fill="currentColor" viewBox="0 0 24 24">
                          <path
                            d="M10 9h4V6h3l-5-5-5 5h3v3zm-1 1H6V7l-5 5 5 5v-3h3v-4zm14 2l-5-5v3h-3v4h3v3l5-5zm-9 3h-4v3H7l5 5 5-5h-3v-3z">
                          </path>
                          <path d="M0 0h24v24H0z" fill="none"></path>
                        </svg>
                      </div>
                    </mat-card-content>
                  </mat-card>
                </cdk-drop-list>
              </mat-grid-tile>
            </mat-grid-list>
          </div>
        </mat-grid-tile>
      </mat-grid-list>
    </div>
  </div>
```

And this is for mobile:

```
<div class="d-flex flex-column d-block d-sm-none">
  <div style="height: 50vh">
      <app-map-element></app-map-element>
  </div>
  <div style="height: 50vh">
    <app-list></app-list>
  </div>
</div>
```

and map component looks like this:

```
<div id="map" class="map"></div>
<form class="form-inline">
    <label>Measurement type &nbsp;</label>
    <select id="type">
      <option value="length">Length (LineString)</option>
      <option value="area">Area (Polygon)</option>
    </select>
  </form>
```

So any suggestions, would be nice.

Thank you

Or maybe two different applications with sharing API calls?

Comment: Technical complexity aside, this sounds like a nightmare from a user standpoint. I turn my phone or tablet and everything's different?!

Comment: Also, good luck defining "mobile" and "desktop". That's a nebulous world.

Comment: ? That is why I ask. Why you answere like this?? Or so maybe make two different apps with sharing api calls?

Answer (score 1):

Just giving you simple adhoc ways is three different blocks of code for different devices and you can initiate them in different ways,

1. Easiest way is using a plugin [ngx-device-detector](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-device-detector).
   Use the variable in *ngIf cases and load the block only when the device is true.
   This actually doesn't load the unnecessary data.
2. Use media queries (this just hides data) CSS change.

Comment: Use html5 grid and Scss. Works on all devices and media queries not needed

Comment: We won't be getting the same level of control that we get through media queries.

Comment: I don't believe that statement. Please explain.

Answer (score 0):

Bootstrap is the way to go. You should check it out

Comment: That is bootstrap: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/display/